# How to generate url for the s3 object without expiring?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have uploaded an object with the

```
 client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                      aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
 response = client.put_object(
                    Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Body=in_mem_file.getvalue(), Key=str(img_name))
```

and I'm generating the URL by

```
url = client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',  Params={
                                                'Bucket': BUCKET_NAME, 'Key': str(img_name)}, ExpiresIn=518400)
```

I need to generate the URL without expiring in some cases. Is it possible to generate url without expiring in s3 bucket?

Comment: You just have to make the object public to do that, but then anyone can access it. Presigned URLs are valid until the credentials that created them expire or for a maximum of 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to generate the URL without expiring in some cases

Its **not possible**. If you don't want to regenerate links every 7 days, then you have to look at other solutions for sharing S3 files. Often [CloudFront with S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/) is used. Otherwise, you need fully custom solution tailored to your specific need.

Answer (score 1):

If the object is public, it has a permanent url of the form:

```
def get_object_url(region, bucket, object_key)
    return f"https://{bucket}.s3.{region}.amazonaws.com/{object_key}"
```

Otherwise, you cannot have a permanent link.